# Session/cookie management in Apache JMeter

Tags: java, session, cookies, jmeter, session-cookies

We have a simple performance test flow in an application.

1. We login
2. Search based on some criteria
3. repeat searches for different parameters.

We are using Jmeter to do a performance testing. We need to have multiple threads running to test this in a scalable manner.

The way we currently have this arranged is:

```
-Test Plan
  - Thread Group
      - Cookie Manager
      - Login To application
      - Search on param 1
      - Search on param 2
  - results summary table
  - Summary report
```

So basically we have summary return table and report present on plan level while cookie manager is present on thread group level.

When I run for one thread it runs fine and completes well. When I scale it to multiple threads, as soon as the next thread kicks off, the session for the last thread is invalidated. This causes failures for all the already running threads due to newly spawned thread.

I reached this result with observation:

1. If I run multiple threads, only last thread has got valid responses in result summary tree

2. If I run with 2 threads with ramp up period as 10 seconds, which means each thread gets time to finish itself, then both of them run successfully.

As per my understanding each thread login's into application and since cookie manager is at thread level, the values will be maintained for session id for each thread respectively? But what is causing the override of the session id value between threads?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Copied from jmeter documentation:

> The last element is a HTTP Cookie
>   Manager . A Cookie Manager should be
>   added to all web tests - otherwise
>   JMeter will ignore cookies. **By adding
>   it at the Thread Group level, we
>   ensure that all HTTP requests will
>   share the same cookies.**

From chapter "4.2.2 Logic Controllers" in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html.

**EDIT**: I guess you should use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller to group your requests together with Cookie Manager.

Answer (score 7):

I think that Andrey's answer cannot help. He quotes that each request will use the same cookies BUT according to jmeter manual:

> Each JMeter thread has its own "cookie storage area".

As far as I understand the question, you want each thread to share the same session ID cookie. So it seems to me you need to have two thread groups and execute them consecutively. First thread group (with a single thread that executes once only) should login and save the session cookie value to a global parameter (perhaps you need to use jmeter's scripting capabilities).
Then set that cookie in the cookie manager of the second thread group.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 to this.

*Is it possible to "propagate" cookies through different Thread Groups of the same Test Plan?
No. JMeter threads are intended to represent independent users, so cookies and variables are local to a thread.*

As per [this](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-cookie-manager-td544523.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the ramp up time. I ran into the same issue where the ramp up time was about 1 second then I increased it to 3 seconds per thread and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open the user.properties present in the bin folder of JMeter

Edit it and add the following line:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Save it and run the script. I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First change your code to:

```
jmeter.properties
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
CookieManager.name.prefix=mycookie_
```

Next, add a HTTP cookie manager in the same thread group as your java sampler.

Then in your java sampler add:

```
JMeterVariables jmv = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> it = jmv.getIterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String,Object> v = it.next();
    System.out.println("name: " + v.getKey() + " value: " + v.getValue());
}
```