# Cannot save cookies for JMETER

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I'm new with Jmeter and by default sorry for dump question.

I want to start with the most basic testing for web site. I want to login to application and navigate to specific page. Basically, that is it for now.

I was fighting with this issue but unfortunately I cannot save cookies properly. I use the following test scenario:
[image: scenario]

However, after I start to run scenario I can see that login was executed successfully, but navigation on page redirect to Login page.

[image: scenario]

It seems that cookies were not actually saved.

Please any advice. If you require any additional information I'll provide everything what is needed.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389464/session-cookie-management-in-apache-jmeter?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you say login did not work or work ?

Why don't you first look in View Results Tree at first "Http Request login" sampler response to check that login was successful ?

To see if Cookies are transmitted check Request Tab in View Results Tree to see if Cookies are transmitted.

From what you show it seems you are playing login twice, check your Thread Group for number of iterations ? if you set more than 1, maybe your application does not allow double login.

Comment: @PeterSmith I saw that actual response (Response data tab) in 'Http Request login' is ok. Now I checked about iterations and you was absolutely right. Working now. Thanks.